# How common is it for "windmill" to be pronounced rhyming with "wheel?"

Tags: pronunciation

I've always heard "windmill" pronounced to rhyme with "ill."  I've recently heard it pronounced to rhyme with "wheel."

Is this common?  Is it a regional thing?

All the online dictionaries I have consulted seem to give a pronunciation that would rhyme with "ill."  I found none that looked like it would rhyme with "wheel."

---

I heard my brother-in-law pronounce "windmill" to rhyme with "wheel" several times recently.  If it were just him, I wouldn't ask - individual people come up with odd things.  Coincidentally, however, I heard Michal Douglas' character Steve Keller in the TV series *The Streets of San Francisco* pronounce "windmill" to rhyme with "wheel" as well.  That leads me to think it may be in common use somewhere.

If it is of any help, my brother-in-law is from Colorado and [Wikipedia says that Michael Douglas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Douglas) is from New Jersey.

---

Edit 2023-10-11:

I was listening to a recording of "Little Deuce Coupe" made by The Surfaris (not the original by The Beach Boys,) and heard the same mill/meel pronunciation.  Oddly, the word "still" was pronounced correctly.

Comment: I thought this was a Southern pronunciation of /ɪ/.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_American_English#Modern_phonology) suggests [ɪjə̯] or [iə̯].

Comment: OED just has /ɪ/ .... But it does have (d), meaning you can omit the /d/ sound.

Comment: @Henry:  I'm about as Southern as you can get:  Born in Louisiana, grew up in Louisiana, Arkansas, Missouri, and Texas.  I've always heard "windmill" to rhyme with "ill."

Comment: @JRE - but you or your neighbours may pronounce *ill* in a way others hear *eel*

Comment: @Henry:  Nope.  I hear the difference.  I pronounce it "ill" like it ought to be.

Comment: @JRE Does you relative also pronounce "fill" like "feel" and "mill" like "meal," or is it just this one word?

Comment: @alphabet: I really don't know. We spent some time travelling together over the last couple of weeks.  We happened to be passing through areas with lots of windmills, which got us talking about them. "Fill" didn't come up in conversation that I remember.

Comment: @JRE We'd need the answer to this, unfortunately, to determine if he has an accent that consistently changes the pronunciation of /ɪl/ or if it's just a single word. A recording of him saying those words (mill, meal, windmill) would also help us answer your question.

Comment: @alphabet:  I think not.  I'm asking if this is a common thing.  If it is, then people will recognize it.  If it is uncommon then I don't see how a recording of a couple of words would help.

Comment: Where are you talking about? And which social class? English varies enormously in vowel pronunciation world wide, especially at word ends, and especially with resonants like /l/.

Comment: @JohnLawler:  I gave two examples in the question - two people from different regions in the USA who both use the same pronunciation.

Comment: It's well within the boundaries of individual variation. The question seems to arise from noticing two individuals with what sounds like unusual variation. Epenthesis with resonant finals is common.

Comment: @JRE There are some accents that characteristically have this phenomenon in *all* words (this is called the *fill-feel merger*). There are also a number of /l/-related phonetic phenomena that can cause these kinds of shifts. I don't think this question is answerable without more details. If you know enough IPA to give a very narrow phonetic transcription that would also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia cites linguists that have noted that the "ee" and "ih" vowel sounds (phonemically transcribed as /iː/ and /ɪ/) are systematically merged for some speakers before the consonant /l/: [Fill–feel merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/l/#Fill%E2%80%93feel_merger). There is however no mention of this feature being particularly characteristic of speakers from Colorado or New Jersey:

> The fill–feel merger is a conditioned merger of the vowels /ɪ/ and /iː/ before /l/ that occurs in some accents. In Europe, it is commonly found in Estuary English. Otherwise it is typical of certain accents of American English. The heaviest concentration of the merger is found in, but not necessarily confined to, Southern American English

The merged vowel may be similar to an /ɪ/ sound (which would imply pronouncing "wheel" more like "whill" rather than pronouncing "windmill" like "windmeel") but can also be more similar to an /i/ sound, per [Chapter 9 of the Atlas of North American English](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/phono_atlas/Atlas_chapters/Ch09_2nd.rev.pdf).

(Compare the variable identification of [vowel before "r" in words like "hero" and "Sirius"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72065/eer-vowel-accent-dialect-variation), which for some North American speakers sounds more like /ɪ/ while for others it sounds more like /iː/). Another possible variant might be something that could be transcribed as [ɪə̯] or [iə̯].

The feel-fill merger is mentioned as a possible feature of Utah English speech here:

- Savage, David Matthew, "[How We Feel About How We Talk: A Language Attitude Survey of Utah English](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=6577&context=etd)" (2014). Theses and Dissertations. 5578.

That's at least nearer to Colorado than the places listed in Wikipedia / the Atlas of North American English.

Comment: Hmm.  That is odd.  I've lived in Arkansas, Louisiana, and Texas and never noted the fill-feel thing - and that's where the Wikipedia map shows it. The only two cases I've seen were both from outside the regions shown on the map.

Comment: The asker never specified if this affected any words other than *windmill.*

Comment: @alphabet: Yes, I know. The question asks how common it is for "windmill" to rhyme with "wheel" (oh, I guess this is an edit ... anyway). For anyone who has the fill-feel merger, this pair of words will rhyme (setting aside issues of stress). I don't have information about any special characteristics of the word "windmill" that cause it to be rhymed with "wheel" outside of accents with the fill-feel merger, so this answer is clearly incomplete, but I don't think anything in it is inaccurate.

Comment: @herisson It's accurate, but fairly likely to be irrelevant to the asker's question about their friend's pronunciation.

Comment: @herisson:  I think your answer is about the best that can be found.  If there's enough people who use the "eel" pronunciation for it to have been studied and given a name, then that's good enough for my purposes.  It's obviously more than just an odd pronunciation that my brother-in-law came up with, while still being uncommon enough for me to have never noticed it before.

Answer (score -4):

The pronounciation at the end comes down to the *"ill"* and *"i"* remotely is also sounded like an *"e"*. For a person who speaks multiple languages "ill" and "eel" will sound same by extending the sound of "e" by a bit.

Shortly, they don't rhyme on Face level but do rhyme when pronounciated a bit diffrently.
also the factor of ***Alliteration*** make the "w" in both the words rhyme when said in succession of each other.

---

Upon breaking the word as "wind-mi-ll" and "whe-ll" the syllables "mi" and "whe" rhyme by the sound of "e" continuing to the fact that the subtle sound of "l's" also add to it. It can be said that its a multisyllable rhyme..and at the very base level words can be rhymed easily if they are twisted or turned in a certain way and accents of people around the world do just that. so its not a much of a surprise that people from diffrent placea would argue if these two or any other two words rhyme or not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: *For a person who speaks multiple languages "ill" and "eel" will sound same* - I speak English and German, and I hear a difference.  My brother-in-law speaks only English.  To my ears "ill" and "eel" are completely different.  "Ill" has a short "i" while "eel" has a long "e."

Comment: well that depends upon language to language..from where i come from, i.e. south Asia..many languages have the "ill" sound like "eel"

Comment: @Pheonix:  We are discussing English, not Asian languages.  I'm not asking about rhyming, anyway.  The question is about how common a certain pronunciation is.

Comment: For a person who speaks French, Spanish or Portuguese, for example but not just any language.

Comment: if the question is how common is a certain pronounciation?..you will probably never get a proper defined answer.. >The problem with "handmade" phonetics is that there's no standard. Different writers will split different phonemes and transcribe them differently... Source:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_talk:Manual_of_Style/Pronunciation/Archive_1

Comment: @Pheonix:  The pronunciation will belong to a dialect.  There are [maps of the extent of various dialects in the USA](https://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/govbeat/wp/2013/12/02/what-dialect-to-do-you-speak-a-map-of-american-english/) and probably for other countries as well.